# Migration to new MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, migration-assistant

I have upgraded to from a 2011 13" MacBook Pro to a 2012 13" MacBook Pro... found serious software slow down and wheel of death after installing Mountain Lion on 2011 MacBook Pro... Upgraded to 2012 MacBook Pro and used Migration assistant... dont have the huge slow down, but dont know if new machine is performing slower than its could.

Question: Is there any way that Migration assistance could copy problem software to new MacBook Pro or does it automatically honour newer software?

Comment: Also, need to add: Did a Disk Util. clean install on Mntn Lion on 2011 MBP and its running 100%... Just want to be sure i dont have gremlins on the new MBP using Migration Assistant

Answer (score 1):

Usually when migrating to a new computer whether it is with migration assistent or other software, it will always cause your hard drive to be fragmented which will cause your computer to run slow. In some cases it can be very fragmented. I would recommend running [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/) this utility is incredible how much faster it can make a computer, especially after migrating to a new computer. P.S. in the future I would recommend using [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) for all of your migrating, it is a lot easier and safer way to migrate.